# c# retrieve file/folder path from selected file/folder in Context Menu Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows, shell, contextmenu, windows-explorer

I'm trying to implement an option in the context menu of Windows Explorer for any file and any folder.
I have accomplish this by writing into regedit.

```
Using Microsoft.Win32;
...
RegistryKey key;
// Register to any file
key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CLASSES\*\shell\MyProject");
key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CLASSES\*\shell\MyProject\command");
// Register to folder
key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CLASSES\Folder\shell\MyProject");
key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\CLASSES\Folder\shell\MyProject\command");
// Default value points to the app
key.SetValue("", Application.StartupPath + @"\MyProject.exe");
key.Close();
```

The application opens as I want, however I have no clue how to grab the path of file/folder that was selected in the context menu. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess it's provided as your first command line argument to your main method. But I'm not sure if you have to place some markup like "%1" or something in the registry "command" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the registry key to

```
key.SetValue("", Application.StartupPath + @"\MyProject.exe %1");
```

So `%1` is replaced with the selected file/folder. In your main method you can access this via:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Selected file/folder: {0}", args[0]);
}
```

Unfortunatly this will not work for multi-selection. Placing `%2` etc is of no use. If multiple files or folders are selected your application gets called for each of them seperatly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of René Vogt is great only this line:

```
key.SetValue("", Application.StartupPath + @"\MyProject.exe %1");
```

should be:

```
key.SetValue("", Application.StartupPath + @"\MyProject.exe \"%1\"");
```

Without the quotation marks the `args[]` array contains multiple strings when the directory or file path contains whitespaces.

Comment: I'm using WPF C# app. I see in registery it creates the key and value. But, how do i get the current path of folder or file in WPF C# app?